# How to calculate the standard deviation of noise for an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, noise

I'm currently testing out various denoising algorithms on noisy images. Is there a way of measuring the standard deviation of the noise in the images that I'm denoising (before and after) with OpenCV(python) or any easier method?

Comment: can you compute the mean average of the noise?

Comment: @Micka that would require knowing what is noise and what is not.  You can measure the standard deviation of the image as a whole, but not the noise itself.

Comment: Before denoising the noisy image, the noisy image needs to be created from the original image. Is there a way to check how much noise you add on to the original image and get the standard deviation of the noise from that?

Comment: If you knew what was noise and what wasn't, then we wouldn't have the need for all these denoising algorithms in the first place. :D

Comment: If you can find a uniform color area (no texture), then compute the std from that ROI. For example, see my ImageMagick script, denoise, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/denoise/index.php. It shows where I get a rectangular region from the noisy image and compute the std of that region.

Comment: if you have access to the camera, you could try to extract the noise distribution for a given parameter set by designing appropriate experiments.

Comment: another way zo test denoising is to add noise, which is known then.

Comment: Use wiener filter! in matlab you can get the standard deviation with just a command: [J,noise_out] = wiener2(I,[m n])

Answer (score 0):

I would try to pursue this by taking the image before denoise and applying a bitwise_and to it from the denoised image. This would give you just the noise. Then you could take the standard deviation and compare between the denoising algorithms.

Comment: Ok, is this the same as method noise? If not, how would I go about getting the method noise as well (not related to the original question)

Comment: @PeterParker, I'm not sure what you mean by method noise. I've never heard that term before.

Comment: its the difference between the true image and the denoised image

Comment: I guess it is then @PeterParker. This seems like the best option.